# How can upgrade a wordpress plugin manually using the option “add new”

Tags: wordpress, plugins, installation, upgrade

I need to test a upgrade implementation before upload the code on the repository and be public to everyone but I can't find how.

Replacing the old code for the new code via FTP isn't work because the additional files will be there.

I am trying to upload the new plugin through "add new" but wp isn't allow to upgrade the plugin.

Anyone know how to test an upgrade method :

add_filter( 'upgrader_pre_install', 'xxx_plugin_backup', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter( 'upgrader_post_install', 'xxx_plugin_restore', 10, 2);

This code is using o wordpress plugin that need to keep some configuration files inside of the plugin folder after the installation. But how can I test before to upload on the wordpress repository ?

Comment: I did update, this code is using on a wordpress plugin that trying to keep some configuration files inside of the installation folder after a new update. The question is how to test, manually.

Comment: Manually is possible to update a plugin by replacing the files via FTP, but how can install the plugin manually without replacing the files?

The "add new" option allow to install the plugin manually but not update, any chance to hack the wordpress in order to allow update using "add new" in order to test the plugin update method?